# I can't insert a lots of rows to column in a table with other auto_increment column.

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-into

> I've got the table with auto_increment ID column and i want to add another column, which would has copied numbers from ID column ( for example named copied_ID), so i
>   want to have two the same colmuns, one of them auto_increment. 
>   [before_photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gzIj.png)
>   I've tried:

```
insert into my_table (copied_ID) select ID from my_table;
```

> But then i've got:
>   [after_photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAvsy.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another column:

```
-- Add the column to the table, if necessary
alter table my_table add column copied_id int; 

-- Update the table
update my_table 
    set copied_id = id;
```

`insert` inserts new *rows*.  You want to add a new *column*.